# In Android Studio, Error in Gradle: HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD '..kxml2-2.3.0.jar'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kxml2

I am new to android development, am using Android studio.

getting the following error after I've just created my new project.

[image]

have checked proxy settings using the Settings --> HTTP proxy --> check connection and I am able to connect properly. Since that is ruled out. I took a look at the idea.log

I am getting an exception which seems very much like its not able to download the jar: 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/kxml2/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar'

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/kxml2/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar'.
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawHead(HttpClientHelper.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performHead(HttpClientHelper.java:62)
```

when I launch the url it says the jar is not available: shows a JSON with a 404 error message.

Is there any way that I can change the URL to one that works or just download it from other sources and skip this step altogether?

Please help me out.

Environment details:

```
IDE: Android Studio (build #AI-135.1538390, 23 Oct 2014 00:00) 
OS: Windows 8.1 (6.3, amd64) 
JRE: 1.8.0_20-b26 (Oracle Corporation) 
JVM: 25.20-b23 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)
```

**EDIT:**

**build.gradle: project level:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "neo.com.app2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

**build.gradle: top-level**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your `build.gradle`, top-level and project-level

Comment: @gio: have changed the original post with required details.

Comment: Looks like it's internal usage of Android Studio, you use old version of AS, please update it to [latest stable](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)